# If a subrectangle $R$ lies in both one of the rectangles $Q_i$ and one of the rectangles $Q_j^{\prime}$, $\cdots$ (Munkres Analysis on Manifolds)

Tags: integration, measure-theory, multivariable-calculus

I am reading "Analysis on Manifolds" by James R. Munkres.
On p.94, Munkres wrote as follows:

> Divide the collection of all subrectangles $R$ determined by $P$ into two disjoint subcollections $\mathcal{R}$ and $\mathcal{R^{\prime}}$, so that each rectangle $R\in\mathcal{R}$ lies in one of the rectangles $Q_i$, and each rectangle $R\in\mathcal{R^{\prime}}$ lies in one of the rectangles $Q_j^{\prime}$.

I think there is a possibility that a subrectangle $R$ determined by $P$ lies in both one of the rectangles $Q_i$ and one of the rectangles $Q_j^{\prime}$.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible that a subrectangle $R$ lies in both rectangles $Q_i$ and $Q_j'$, but it does not alter the outcome.  In this case we have

$$U(f,P) - L(f,P) < \sum_{R \in \mathcal{R}}(M_R(f) - m_R(f))v(R) + \sum_{R \in \mathcal{R'}}(M_R(f) - m_R(f))v(R)\\ \leqslant 2M \epsilon'+2\epsilon'v(Q), $$

with **strict inequality** as the two sums may include common terms.

Nevertheless, the bounds on those sums imply that $U(f,P) - L(f,P) < \epsilon$ which proves integrability

Comment: RRL, Thank you very much for your answer.

Comment: @tchappyha: You're welcome.  Good observation.  Munkres does not always make things crystal clear.

Answer (score 0):

I think Munkres didn't write anything wrong.

If a subrectangle $R$ determined by $P$ lies in both one of the rectangles $Q_i$ and one of the rectangles $Q'_j$, then let $R$ be a member of either $\mathcal{R}$ or $\mathcal{R}'$, but not both.